# deleting existing docker images from EC2 using Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, devops, aws-ecr

I have to run some containers from the images present in AWS ECR.As i need to automate this i am using Jenkins.

I have 4 ECR repositories as soon as a new version of image comes in this repository my jenkins job will trigger and create a new container.So as the code of microservice is changing and i am getting new image in ECR i have to delete the old container and run the new one on same port.

I am using "Send file or execute commands over SSH" of Jenkins to do this.
Then i am providing commands like below

```
   aws ecr get-login --no-include-email > login.sh
   bash login.sh
   docker pull 944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo- 
     docker:latest
   docker run -d -p 8081:80 944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east- 
        1.amazonaws.com/demo-docker:latest
```

Now the problem is whenever i get new image i have to stop the earlier container running and for that i need container-id. I dont know to fetch container-id here to stop the container.Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can give your container also a name (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name) or you can get the container id with docker `docker ps -q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already given but one important thing that I will never suggest to remove container using

```
docker rm -f
```

which sends **SIGKILL** directly without grace period.

The best way to deal is to first [stop the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) then remove the container, It sends **SIGTERM** first, then, after a grace period, **SIGKILL**.

Also if you are not running ECS then the hardcoded name is enough, as you are not running both containers simultaneously, so

```
docker run --rm --name my_container -d -p 8081:80 944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-docker:latest
```

so during deployment all you need `docker stop my_container` it will stop and the container also will release the name, so you are good to go deploy again with same name.

```
docker run --rm --name my_container -d -p 8081:80 944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-docker:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

to get the containers you may use:

```
docker ps -q --filter "ancestor=944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east- 
        1.amazonaws.com/demo-docker:latest"
```

so to delete them :

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -q --filter "ancestor=944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east- 
        1.amazonaws.com/demo-docker:latest")
```

you can add `-a` to `docker ps` to delete not running containers also

> ancestor  Filters containers which share a given image as an ancestor.
>   Expressed as image-name[:tag], image id, or image@digest

Comment: Great ThankYou. Any similar commands if i want to delete image ?

Comment: image name is always the same I think?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the command to remove downloaded images from EC2 server:

```
docker image prune
```

Let me know if you face any issues running it.